# Jsonp and jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have problems making an JSONP with jquery mobile. I can´t received the data.

I put the code:

Could someone help me?

html:

```
</head> 
<body> 
<script>

 $(function() {

$("#callAjax").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://atcsat.es/App/ws/listadoModelos.php?callback=?',
        type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
        error : function (){ document.title='error'; }, 
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    }); 
});



});

</script>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page One</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
<input id="callAjax" type="button" value="Errores" />

</div>
<div id="listadoListas"></div>
</div>
```

When i execute it says [object,Object]
could someone help me about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Object** is your **jsonp** response data. You can add in your page like this:

```
var listadoListas = ""; 
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://atcsat.es/App/ws/listadoModelos.php?callback=',
    type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
    error : function (){ document.title='error'; }, 
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            listadoListas += '<p>ID:'+data[key].ID+'</p><p>CodFamProducto:'+data[key].CodFamProducto+'</p><p>Descripcion:'+data[key].Descripcion+'</p><p>Marca:'+data[key].Marca+'</p></br>';
        })
        //alert(listadoListas);
        $("#listadoListas").html(listadoListas)            

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[object,Object] corresponds to the code "alert(data);". This means that your request is working properly.
If you want to parse the data content you should probably add something like:

```
for (var i in data) {
    alert(i + " : " + data[i]);
}
```